# JsView Cannot read property '_cId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsviews

I am experiencing weird behavior related to observing property changes on items that were created dynamically.

**Scenario:** 
I have a page where my user creates contacts. The number of contacts they create varies (upon a few conditions).

**My current solution:** 
I have created a contact template. Every time user clicks on Add button, I add a new contact object using the Observable API. Now the problem is when I try deleting the contact, the contact is deleted from the underlying array but it **DOES NOT** delete from the UI. In addition I get an exception thrown at me saying: "Cannot read property '_cId' of undefined".

```
<div id="page"></div>

<script id="PageTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <!-- More elements here -->

    <button class="add-contact-btn">Add</button>    
    <div id="Contacts" data-link="{for Contacts tmpl='ContactTemplate'}"></div>

    <!-- More elements here -->
</script>

<script id="ContactTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div>
        <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" data-link="FirstName" />

        <br />

        <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" data-link="LastName" /> 

        <br />
        <br />

        <a class="delete-contact" href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var PageContext = new ContactPage();

$(function () {
    PageContext.init();
});

function ContactPage() {
    var addContactBtn = 'button.add-contact-btn';
    var deleteContactLink = 'a.delete-contact';

    this.UnsavedChanges = false;
    this.Contacts = [];

    var contactHandler = function (event, eventArgs) {
        var dataContext = event.data;
        $.observable(dataContext).setProperty('UnsavedChanges', true);
    };

    this.init = function () {
        var that = this;

        $.templates({
            PageTemplate: '#PageTemplate',
            ContactTemplate: '#ContactTemplate'
        });

        $.link.PageTemplate('#page', this)
            .on('click', addContactBtn, null, function (event) {
                $.observable(that.Contacts).insert({
                    FirstName: "",
                    LastName: ""
                });
            })
            .on('click', deleteContactLink, null, function () {
                var index = $.view(this).index;
                $.observable(that.Contacts).remove(index);
            });

        $([this.Contacts]).on('arrayChange', null, this, function (event, eventArgs) {
            if (eventArgs.change === 'insert') {
                // Exception is thrown: "Cannot read property '_cId' of undefined" when I click on Delete
                $(eventArgs.items).on('propertyChange', null, event.data, contactHandler);

                // however if i run it like this, then no exceptions are thrown
                //$(eventArgs.items).on('propertyChange', contactHandler);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

I have created a JsFiddle to demonstrate the exception and I am hoping someone can give me guidance on what to do to solve it.

http://jsfiddle.net/parthsha/dLo33ch9/3/

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you are right, it needs a null check here:

```
found = (data = events[l].data) && data.cb._cId === evData._cId;
```

I will change it, in the next update, to:

```
found = (data = events[l].data) && data.cb && data.cb._cId === evData._cId;
```

Comment: Does event.target point to the PageContext object or the actual contact object (i.e. the one which has FirstName, LastName properties)? I am trying to get access to the PageContext object.

Comment: My current workaround to this problem is declaring the event handler within the init method and then accessing a reference to the PageContext using the "var that = this;" pattern. However I do not like it because it hinders testing of the method. I think the root source of the problem is in jQuery if you specify data in .on() method, it is accessible within the function by accessing event.data. However, in JsView, event.data is being either overwritten for internal purposes.

Comment: Using your code from the jsfiddle, but with the two changes above, it works. So you have $(eventArgs.items).on('propertyChange', contactHandler); - and event.target in the handler corresponds to the eventArgs.items[0] for example, which is the object with FirstName and LastName properties.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to set UnsavedChanges on the individual contact objects but rather the PageContext object. If I write $(eventArgs.items).on('propertyChange', null, event.data, contactHandler); I can pass the PageContext to the contactHandler but I can't delete the contact later on.

Comment: Ah - yes I see what you mean. I have removed my suggestion from my answer above. Your code will work with update (the null check fix) - maybe you can include it as a local fix, while waiting for the update? Otherwise, as you say, you need to declare the handler withing the scope of `that`. Similarly you could use observeAll: $.observable(this).observeAll(function(ev, eventArgs) { if (eventArgs.change === "set") { $.observable(that).setProperty('UnsavedChanges', true); } }); BTW I just posted a related reply to another question, here:  stackoverflow.com/a/31344290/1054484.